# Jest describe.each or test.each not working

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

Few months back I wrote data driven test cases in C# using Nunit TestCase Attribute . Today I was looking for same feature in Jest for frontend. I found jest has **describe.each** and **test.each** for this in version >= 23.0 . I upgraded jest to "jest": "^23.2.0" and same for types. but its not working and gives error **each is undefined** . I debugged and find out that its **jest-zone-patch** wraps **test** and **describe** and their they set **only** and **skip** not **each** function

```
["xit", "fit", "test", "it"].forEach(methodName => {
const originaljestFn = env[methodName];
env[methodName] = function(description, specDefinitions, timeout) {
arguments[1] = wrapTestInZone(specDefinitions);
return originaljestFn.apply(this, arguments);
};
if (methodName === "test" || methodName === "it") {
env[methodName].only = env["fit"];
env[methodName].skip = env["xit"];
```

I added

```
env[methodName].each = originaljestFn.each;
```

and it worked.

I am new to jest and might be totally wrong . Am I totally missing something or do i need to do something else than upgrading jest and types.
**Note:types do have each function for both describe and test.**